# Cyclic Tree with new ParentId and ChildId

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, cyclic-dependency

I have a hierarchy tree JSON with multiple level of nesting. When i am trying to loop through the JSON for displaying tree structure in UI. I am ending up with cyclic redundancy since parent ID is same at different level. I need to add unique identifiers for parentID and ID, so in recursive call it does not end up in infinite loop.

Sample JSON :

```
[
  {
    "id": "12",
    "text": "Man"
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "parentId": "12",
    "text": "Boy"
  },
  {
    "id": "9",
    "parentId": "6",
    "text": "Boy-Boy"
  },
  {
    "id": "13",
    "parentId": "9",
    "text": "Boy-Boy-Boy"
  },
  {
    "id": "7",
    "parentId": "12",
    "text": "Other"
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "parentId": "7",
    "text": "Boy"
  },
  {
    "id": "9",
    "parentId": "6",
    "text": "Boy-Boy"
  },
  {
    "id": "13",
    "parentId": "9",
    "text": "Boy-Boy-Boy"
  }
```

I have tried by adding depth to each level but not able to maintain the ParentId and Id relationship.

```
var depthArray = []

function addDepth(arr, depth = 0) {
  arr.forEach(obj => {


  obj.id =  obj.id + '-' + depth;
  if(obj.children !== undefined) {
  addDepth(obj.children, depth + 1)
}})
return arr;
}

[
  {
    "id": "12",
    "text": "Man"
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "parentId": "12",
    "text": "Boy"
  },
  {
    "id": "9",
    "parentId": "6",
    "text": "Boy-Boy"
  },
  {
    "id": "13",
    "parentId": "9",
    "text": "Boy-Boy-Boy"
  },
  {
    "id": "7",
    "parentId": "12",
    "text": "Other"
  },
  {
    "id": "6-1",
    "parentId": "7",
    "text": "Boy"
  },
  {
    "id": "9-1",
    "parentId": "6-1",
    "text": "Boy-Boy"
  },
  {
    "id": "13-1",
    "parentId": "9-1",
    "text": "Boy-Boy-Boy"
  }
]
```

Comment: Why do you have duplicate nodes? And is it possible to that same node has two parents? And lastly, what are you trying to achieve? It's not very clear what the problem is.

Comment: @Maaz Syed Adeeb,   the hierarchy tree has cyclic and inter relations hence duplicate nodes are given. yes  the same nodes can have two parents since it is cyclic.  I am trying to generate tree structure, where if there are cyclic relationships i want to give a duplicate nodes an id that is unique so that the whole tree structure has unique node ids. hope this helps

Comment: Btw copy of ID 9 / parentId 6 is very strange - probably some typo ?

Answer (score 0):

Your recursion does not work, what about this ?
But not sure how to rename IDs:

```js
'use strict';
function addDepth(arr, id, depth) {
  if(depth === undefined) depth = 0;
  if(id !== undefined)
    arr.forEach(obj => {

        if(id == obj.parentId) {
        if(depth) obj.parentId += '-' + depth;
        addDepth(arr, obj.id, depth + 1)
      }
    })
  else arr.forEach(obj => { addDepth(arr, obj.id, depth); });
  return arr;
}

console.log(addDepth(
[
  {
    "id": "12",
    "text": "Man"
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "parentId": "12",
    "text": "Boy"
  },
  {
    "id": "9",
    "parentId": "6",
    "text": "Boy-Boy"
  },
  {
    "id": "13",
    "parentId": "9",
    "text": "Boy-Boy-Boy"
  },
  {
    "id": "7",
    "parentId": "12",
    "text": "Other"
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "parentId": "7",
    "text": "Boy"
  },
  {
    "id": "9",
    "parentId": "6",
    "text": "Boy-Boy"
  },
  {
    "id": "13",
    "parentId": "9",
    "text": "Boy-Boy-Boy"
  }
]
));
```

Hard to guess how structure may look like, but made a supposed output by hand and then similar code - looking up only (not sure how to distinguish same records with parentId difference):

```
12          Man
12 6        Man Boy
12 6 9      Man Boy Boy-Boy
12 6 9 13   Man Boy Boy-Boy Boy-Boy-Boy
12 7        Man Other
12 7        Man Other Boy
12 7 6 9    Man Other Boy Boy-Boy
12 7 6 9 13 Man Other Boy Boy-Boy Boy-Boy-Boy
```

```js
var data = GetData();
var arr = [data[0].text], parent;
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    if(parent = data[i].parentId) {
        arr.push(data[i].text); // we have parentId, so iterate back
        for(var j=i;j >= 0;j--) {
            if(data[j].id == parent) {
                arr.push(data[j].text); // & colect text properties
                if(data[j].parentId) {
                    parent = data[j].parentId;
                    j = i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(arr.reverse().join(" -> "));
    arr = [];
}

function GetData() { return [
    {
      "id": "12",
      "text": "Man"
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "parentId": "12",
      "text": "Boy"
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "parentId": "6",
      "text": "Boy-Boy"
    },
    {
      "id": "13",
      "parentId": "9",
      "text": "Boy-Boy-Boy"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "parentId": "12",
      "text": "Other"
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "parentId": "7",
      "text": "Boy"
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "parentId": "6",
      "text": "Boy-Boy"
    },
    {
      "id": "13",
      "parentId": "9",
      "text": "Boy-Boy-Boy"
    }
];
}
```

Comment: My requirement is I am having a hierarchy tree which has cyclic and inter relations hence duplicate nodes are given, the same nodes can have two parents since it is cyclic. I am trying to generate tree structure, where if there are cyclic relationships i want to give duplicate nodes an id that is unique so that the whole tree structure has unique node ids.